# vscode.env.openExternal does not open URI after upgrading to VSCode 1.36.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Prior to VSCode 1.36 vscode.env.openExternal was working perfect for us.
After upgrading to VSCode 1.36 vscode.env.openExternal fails to open URIs.

Appreciate any insight into how to resolve this.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76606

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/76730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode 1.36.0 broke openExternal.  June Recovery Build version 1.36.1 fixes this issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76882